# Laravel - Laravel Excel - maatwebsite Successfully added image to spreadsheets, the image is 'over cell', how to make it 'in cell'?

Tags: php, laravel, xls, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

Here is my Export Class, function drawings () :

```
public function drawings()
    {
        $drawingCollection = [];        
        $row = 2;
        $column = 'G';

        foreach ($this->reportData as $data) {
            $drawing = new Drawing();
            $drawing->setName('MyImage');
            $drawing->setDescription('Description');
            if($data->{'Foto Toko Depan'})
            {
                $imagePath = storage_path('app/public/' . $data->{'Foto Toko Depan'});
                $drawing->setPath($imagePath);                
                $drawing->setHeight(20);
                $drawing->setWidth(20);
                $drawing->setCoordinates($column . $row);
                $drawingCollection[] = $drawing;
            }
            $row++;
        }

        return $drawingCollection;
   }
```

After downloaded, it looks like this:
[image: Spreadsheet Screenshot]

It looks a mess, because it is 'over' cell, not 'in cell' , is there any way to fix this?

Setting row height was not really useful, because the image is 'over cell'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't achieve that. it works like an overlay. However, you can set the cell height to match the image height, creating a similar effect.

```
public function registerEvents(): array
    {
      return [
                 AfterSheet::class => function(AfterSheet $event) {
                     for ($i =1; $i <= $this->count; $i++) {
                         $event->sheet->getDelegate()->getRowDimension($i)->setRowHeight(100);
                     }
                 }
            ];
    }
```

You can pass the number of rows from your controller like this

```
public function export()
    {
        $count = User::count();
        $export = new UsersExport($count);
        return Excel::download($export, 'users.xlsx');
    }
```